# How get custom field in aspnetusers table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-identity-2

Using CodeFirst migration, i added custom field "Surname" in table aspnetusers in standart db in asp mvc template in VS 2013(sorry for "in"). How get value of "Surname" field, if i logged in?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any action method you could get current user id by calling `User.Identity.GetUserId()` extension method. And you could get extra information by make use of `ApplicationUserManager` like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    string surname = HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
        .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Surname;
}
```

Make sure you added `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` namespace to could use the extension method.

Comment: Oh, goodness. This is what finally allowed me to check the value of a custom property on another user’s account. I needed a way to see if a user’s account was disabled before letting another user interact with them, and I had an `AccountDisabled` Boolean on `ApplicationUser`. This allowed me to check what that Boolean was set to.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have your custom class user?
If yes......so "Surname" just will one of user class properties (sure you need set PUBLIC)

if you just change **TABLE** Into **Database** you can get this property, because identity don't know what is this column, because you don't have any class with this **structure**